# Fuzzy String Search using Longest Common Substring for One Vector using R

Tags: r, fuzzy-search, lcs

What is a good approach to tackle a single vector with 2 million data to achieve the following outcome:-

1. Getting the top "X" number of Longest Common Substring matches
2. Frequency of occurrence of item 1.

Example of a smaller set of data:-

```
x<-c("apple STP port=22 ","chicken STP port=11","WinMS Log 6","Test WinMS Log 7","RT_FLOW WinMS Log 6","Rubbish.local WinMS Log 7")
```

You can see the common word is "STP port=", "WinMS" so the result should show that "STP port=", "WinMS Log " are the top results and provide the frequency of occurrences.

I've read quite a couple method using R such as agrep, stringdist. But it is usually for 2 vectors which is not applicable to my case.

Could anyone enlighten me ?

Revised.

Comment: Your expected results don't exactly match with intution - please clear up any confusion. `port=` (not `STP`) is longest common string in first two strings in vector. `WinMS Log 7` is not found in your vector - `WinMS 7 Log` and `WinEvent Log 7` are.

Comment: Hi, Cpak, thanks for the comment. I've revised the question. In short, what i want to achieve is by finding the top "x" number of LCS in a single vector. I'm unsure if I should classified it as fuzzy pattern search or LCS.